# Is it possible to add Legend to the plot in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I'm trying to add a legend under the plot in scattered chart as shown below. Anyone knows if this is possible?

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending [`StandardXYItemLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardXYItemLabelGenerator.html) is often a useful approach, but the supplied [constructors](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardXYItemLabelGenerator.html) may suffice. For this generator, the [`MessageFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) *ArgumentIndex* values correspond to the **series name**, **domain** and **range**.

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); // etc.
XYItemLabelGenerator generator =
    new StandardXYItemLabelGenerator("{0} {1} {2}", format, format);
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(generator);
renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
```

In addition, you can control individual series labeling with

```
renderer.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(true);
```

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8932920/230513) for `StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the custom label generator that I created:

```
public class LegendXYItemLabelGenerator extends StandardXYItemLabelGenerator
        implements XYItemLabelGenerator, Cloneable, PublicCloneable,
        Serializable {
    private LegendItemCollection legendItems;

    public LegendXYItemLabelGenerator(LegendItemCollection legendItems) {
        super();
        this.legendItems = legendItems;
    }

    @Override
    public String generateLabel(XYDataset dataset, int series, int item) {
        LegendItem legendItem = legendItems.get(series);
        return legendItem.getLabel();
    }
}
```

and then I added this code in addition to @Guilaume's code:

```
renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new LegendXYItemLabelGenerator(plot.getLegendItems()));
```

and here's the result:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the good example. I've suggested an alternative approach in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled on the renderer:

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but it still did now show up. Is there anything else that I probably need to do before? Maybe assigning labels to each plot?

Comment: I think I got it now.. I've created my own item label generator called "LegendXYItemLabelGenerator(..)" and got it to work. In addition to "renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);", I added "renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new LegendXYItemLabelGenerator(plot.getLegendItems()));"

Comment: Is this possible on an `XYAreaRenderer`? I am trying to get it working and I can for the `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` but the same code is not working for the `XYAreaRenderer`.'