# jfree line chart display value for every index

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to create a using jfree chart library line chart and i need to display the value associated with each index in the lineChart, I cannot use a tool tip for this because I am converting the chart into an image , is there a way of displaying the value on top of each index?

Thanks,
Bhavya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your needs, several option are available:

- Use an [`org.jfree.chart.labels.XYItemLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/XYItemLabelGenerator.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146823/is-it-possible-to-add-legend-to-the-plot-in-jfreechart/3158958#3158958) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo).
- Use a suitable one of the many [`org.jfree.chart.annotations`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/package-summary.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604211/jfreechart-draw-arc-on-chart/6620017#6620017).