# JFreeChart create tooltip in ChartPanel

Tags: tooltip, charts, jfreechart

How can I generate a tooltip on chart mouse over in `JFreeChart`?
I tried this:

```
chartPanel.setToolTipText("this is the string");
```

but this does not work. Am I supposed to do something else before? Something like this:

```
chartPanel.createToolTip().
```

I am calling these methods in the `chartMouseMoved` event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most [`ChartFactory`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html) methods include a `boolean tooltips` parameter. Just look in the source for your factory of choice to see how to instantiate a default tooltip generator suitable for the designated renderer. You shouldn't need to handle the events yourself.

Addendum: As you are using `createXYLineChart`, an instance of [`StandardXYToolTipGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardXYToolTipGenerator.html) is supplied by default. The `DEFAULT_TOOL_TIP_FORMAT` is `{0}: ({1}, {2})`; the [`MessageFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) symbols represent the `dataset`, `series` and `item`, respectively. You can use these symbols in your own generator, as shown in this [`XYItemLabelGenerator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146823/is-it-possible-to-add-legend-to-the-plot-in-jfreechart/3158958#3158958), or you can override `generateToolTip()` to return anything at all.

Addendum: Here's an example that shows just the `dataset`:

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setLegendItemToolTipGenerator(
    new StandardXYSeriesLabelGenerator("Legend {0}"));
```

Comment: Thanks,. I am using  createXYLineChart and set the tooltip property to true. But how do I defined where and what to show in each of the tooltips. I I tried doing this in the chartmouseclick and chartMouseMoved but this did not work. I tried did using the methods described above.

Comment: Thanks. But my tooltip string is actually not related to any series or dataset, but on the position at which the mouse is and some calculated value. Let say I want to display the mouse coordinates in a tool tip...

Comment: Just store the `MouseEvent` from your listener in your `StandardXYToolTipGenerator` subclass.

Comment: I used the XYItemLabelGenerator, but the value is displayed on each series point rather than on the mouse location :( Also, can I have it display on top of any annotation that may be on my chart?

Comment: Instead of implementing `XYItemLabelGenerator `, you should extend `StandardXYToolTipGenerator` and add it via the renderer's `setBaseToolTipGenerator()`.

Comment: Example will be very much appreciated