# Display X Values on the XYLineChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I want to display the X values on to the XY line chart As shown below: 
How can i do this?
[image]
**I want to display it like this:**
[image]
Here's my code to display the line Graph:

```
public class LineChartDemo6{
public static void main(String arg[]){
  XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Average Weight");
  series.add(20.0, 20.0);
  series.add(40.0, 20.0);
  series.add(55.0, 20.0);
  series.add(70.0, 20.0);
  XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart
  ("XYLine Chart using JFreeChart", "Age", "Weight",
 xyDataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
  ChartFrame frame1=new ChartFrame("XYLine Chart",chart);
  frame1.setVisible(true);
  frame1.setSize(300,300);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your actual problem? You have a series of data points which ALL have the same height and so you have got a straight line. I can't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust: the problem is i want to display the data above this line as shown [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zNRuE.png). How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `XYItemLabelGenerator` to your plot's renderer, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770477/230513) and this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3158958/230513). It looks like *ArgumentIndex* `{1}` is the domain value.

Addendum: Your [example](http://pastebin.com/siU9Q92p) works fine; it just needs a little extra *margin*.

```
ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
range.setUpperMargin(0.20);
```

[image]

Comment: i've not much familiar with this... i've tried [this](http://pastebin.com/siU9Q92p), but why its not working?

Comment: Thanks man... :) Is there any other way so i can display this graph with my another `XYAreaChart`?

Comment: You could look at a [`Combined*Plot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/package-summary.html) or [separate panels](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7602126/230513).