# I want to enable display xy coordinates on XYSplineRenderer chart

Tags: jfreechart

[image: Want to display XY cordinates at Red circle on image]

I want to enable display xy coordinates on XYSplineRenderer chart.

```
        NumberAxis numberaxis = new NumberAxis("X");
        numberaxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        NumberAxis numberaxis1 = new NumberAxis("Y");
        numberaxis1.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        XYSplineRenderer xysplinerenderer = new XYSplineRenderer();

        XYPlot xyplot = new XYPlot(data1, numberaxis, numberaxis1,
                xysplinerenderer);
        xyplot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        xyplot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        xyplot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

        xyplot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(4D, 4D, 4D, 4D));
        JFreeChart jfreechart = new JFreeChart("XYSplineRenderer",
                JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, xyplot, true);
        addChart(jfreechart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tooltip generator, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770477/230513), or use a label generator, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3158958/230513). Either one or both can be added to your renderer.

Addendum: As noted in comments, the following code solved the problem:

```
StandardXYToolTipGenerator ttG =
    new StandardXYToolTipGenerator("{1},{2}", format, format);
xysplinerenderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(ttG);
```

Comment: I am trying code :-
        StandardXYToolTipGenerator ttG = new StandardXYToolTipGenerator( 
      "{1},{2}", format, format); 
    xysplinerenderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(ttG); 
    
 but it is also not working.

Comment: I know it works for the parent, `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`. Can you adapt, as seen [here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115213), or edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Thanks, It is solved with code. Thanks again for your help.

StandardXYToolTipGenerator ttG = new StandardXYToolTipGenerator( 
      "{1},{2}", format, format); 
    xysplinerenderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(ttG);

Comment: what should be the format in this code if the value in y-axis is float and the value in x-axis is SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")? @trashgod

Comment: Out of context, I'm not sure; please see [ask] a question that includes your [mcve].