# show label when user mouseOver ValueMarker in jFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

Right now i a JFreeChart line graph. I want to add marker to mark some events. I have added the markers. The problem is that the marker labels have started to overlap. I want to solve this by only showing the marker label if the user mouse over's the marker line. How can i capture the mouseover event?

```
Marker tempMarker = new ValueMarker(hour.getFirstMillisecond());        
tempMarker.setPaint(Color.BLACK); 
tempMarker.setLabelAnchor(RectangleAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
tempMarker.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_RIGHT);

//instead of this i want a mouseoverlistner and then show the label
tempMarker.setLabel("Event Name");
```

---

code for mouse over

```
chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent event) {
        //do something on mouse click
    }

    @Override
    public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Entity Type: " + event.getEntity());
    }
});
```

When i mouse over the Marker objects a ChartEntity is sent to the chartMouseMoved. This is the same as when i mouse over other non filled portions of the chart.

Comment: You can capture the mouseover with a `ChartMouseListener` (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172794/jfreechart-dispay-mouse-coordinates-near-to-mouse-as-hints-on-mouse-move), but perhaps you would be satisfied with a tooltip? (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766223/jfreechart-create-tooltip-in-chartpanel)

Comment: @Eric the `ChartMouseListener` does not capture mouse events over the ValueMarker. Tried it already. Markers are added to the plot and the chartmouselistener is on the chart object

Comment: The `ChartMouseListener` should be capturing all the events happening within the chart. Can you post what you have tried? How about addind/removing the markers dynamically when detecting the mouse over a particular entity?

Comment: @Eric i have updated my question with the chartMouseListner code. Basically i have tested with it already and it does not provide any way to identify that the mouse is over a Marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really possible to do this. I got help from @paradoxoff in [this thread](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117416) on the [jfree](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=28) forum. Here is how I achieved it.

1. Download the Annotation files from [Click here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/patches/316/)
2. You only need the `org.jfree.chart.annotations` folder. Add it to your project.
3. Replace the Marker with `Annotations` with this code below

   ```
   XYDomainValueAnnotation tempMarker = new XYDomainValueAnnotation();
   tempMarker.setValue(hour.getFirstMillisecond());

   //set the color of the lines
   switch (priority) {
       case Constants.HIGH_IMPORTANCE:
           tempMarker.setPaint(Color.RED);
           break;
       case Constants.LOW_IMPORTANCE:
           tempMarker.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
           break;
       default:
           tempMarker.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
   }

   // dont set the label
   //tempMarker.setLabel("Event Name");

   //set the Tool Tip which will display when you mouse over.
   tempMarker.setToolTipText("Annotation");

   //format everything
   tempMarker.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f));        
   tempMarker.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
   tempMarker.setLabelAnchor(RectangleAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
   tempMarker.setRotationAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT);

   //add the annotation lines
   plot.addAnnotation(tempMarker);
   ```
4. When you mouse over the annotation lines the tooltip will appear.