# How to customize a tooltip of CategoryPlot items in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, dataset, plot, tooltip, jfreechart

I need to change the format of the default tooltip in the bars drawn in the plot of a chart.

I don't know if my direction of looking at the problem is right. I am looking at the default format for the class `StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator` that is

```
DEFAULT_TOOL_TIP_FORMAT_STRING = "({0}, {1}) = {2}"
```

How can I redefine this value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator.html) sets the [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) *ArgumentIndex* values to the *series*, *category* and *value*. Try this example on your plot.

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator(
    "Series {0}, Category {1}, Value {2}", NumberFormat.getInstance()));
```