# Bar Graph Issue (using JFreechart)

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have created an application that creates bar graph based on inputs read from input file using **JFreeChart**, Now I want that when I point the mouse over a particular bar it shows the input responsible for that bar. How to do this ?

my code to print bar chart-

```
public BarChart(double val[],String title) {

      DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

      for(int i=1;i<=val.length;i++){
          dataset.setValue(val[i-1], "Execution Time(ms)",""+i);
      }


      JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart
      ("BarChart for "+title,"API calls", "Execution Time(ms)", dataset, 
       PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false,true, false);
      CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot(); 
      p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.red); 
      frame1=new ChartFrame("Bar Chart",chart);
      final Rectangle s = WindowBound.getMaximumWindowBounds();
      final Dimension f = frame1.getSize();
      final int w = Math.max(s.width - f.width, 0);
      final int h = Math.max(s.height - f.height, 0);
      final int x = (int) (0.5 * w) + s.x;
      final int y = (int) (0.5 * h) + s.y;
      frame1.setBounds(x-300, y-300, f.width, f.height);
      frame1.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Images/Icon.jpg"));
      frame1.setSize(600,600);

  }
```

Comment: Have you enabled tool tips? Have you tried a custom tooltip renderer?  Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @trashgod - code added...nw tell me what is tooltip renderer, n how to use it..any link that explains it will also do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ChartFactory` in your fragment sets `tooltips` to `true`, so you should see the result produced by the default tool tip renderer when the mouse hovers over a bar. You can change the appearance as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8932920/230513).