# Open detail window when a subtask is clicked on Gantt chart

Tags: jfreechart

I have a Gantt chart which gets the dataset from the database, and I
am stuck on using the `chartMouseClicked`. I want to print the details
of the subtasks whenever I click on any subtask.

`GanttChartDemo23.java`

```
public class GanttDemo23 extends ApplicationFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final TaskSeriesCollection model = new TaskSeriesCollection();

    public GanttDemo23(final String title) {
        super(title);
        final IntervalCategoryDataset dataset = createSampleDataset();
        // create the chart...
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createGanttChart(
                "Gantt Chart", // chart title
                "Flights", // domain axis label
                "Time", // range axis label
                dataset, // data
                true, // include legend
                true, // tooltips
                false // urls
        );
        final CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();

        // add the chart to a panel...
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);


        chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent event) {
                CategoryItemEntity entity = (CategoryItemEntity) event.getEntity();
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                Comparable row = entity.getRowKey();
                Comparable col = entity.getColumnKey();
                panel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(row.toString())));
                panel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(col)));
                panel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(entity.getDataset().getValue(row, col))));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, panel);
            }

            @Override
            public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        //GanttRenderer personnalisÃ©..
        MyRenderer renderer = new MyRenderer(model);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.BLACK);
    }

    /**
     * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938690
     */
    private static class MyRenderer extends GanttRenderer {

        private static final int PASS = 2; // assumes two passes
        private final List<Color> clut = new ArrayList<>();
        private final TaskSeriesCollection model;
        private int row;
        private int col;
        private int index;

        public MyRenderer(TaskSeriesCollection model) {
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int col) {

            if (clut.isEmpty() || this.row != row || this.col != col) {
                initClut(row, col);
                this.row = row;
                this.col = col;
                index = 0;
            }
            int clutIndex = index++ / PASS;
            return clut.get(clutIndex);
        }

        private void initClut(int row, int col) {
            clut.clear();

            TaskSeries series = (TaskSeries) model.getRowKeys().get(row);
            List<Task> tasks = series.getTasks(); // unchecked 

            int taskCount = tasks.get(col).getSubtaskCount();
            taskCount = Math.max(1, taskCount);

            System.out.println("----> " + taskCount);
            String description;

            for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++) {
                description = tasks.get(col).getSubtask(i).getDescription();

                System.out.println(description + ": " + i);
                if (description.equals("Cancelled")) {
                    clut.add(Color.red);
                    System.out.println("green");
                }
                if (description.equals("Delayed")) {
                    clut.add(Color.yellow);
                    System.out.println("yellow");
                }
                if (description.equals("On Time")) {
                    clut.add(Color.blue);
                    System.out.println("blue");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private IntervalCategoryDataset createSampleDataset() {

        System.out.println(java.time.LocalDate.now());  
        int month = java.time.LocalDate.now().getMonthValue();
        int year = java.time.LocalDate.now().getYear();
        int day = java.time.LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth();

        List<String> fltEqps = new ArrayList<>();
        fltEqps.add("DNA");
        fltEqps.add("DNB");
        fltEqps.add("DNC");

        final TaskSeries s1 = new TaskSeries("Scheduled");


        for (String fltEqp : fltEqps) {

            MyConnection dao = new MyConnection();

        final Task t = new Task(fltEqp, date(day, (month-1), year, 00,00), date(day, (month-1), year, 23,59));
        List <FlightDetails> flightDetails = dao.flightDetails(fltEqp, java.time.LocalDate.now());





 /*   This is the Sample of Flight Data, being retrieved from the Db.
        FlightDetails flightDetail1 = new FlightDetails();
        flightDetail1.setArrTime("0830");
        flightDetail1.setDepTime("1030");
        flightDetail1.setDuration("0200");
        flightDetail1.setFltArr("ISB");
        flightDetail1.setFltDep("KHI");
        flightDetail1.setFltDate("2018-10-07");
        flightDetail1.setFltEqp("738");
        flightDetail1.setFltEqpRegNo("DNB");
        flightDetail1.setFltNo("0502");
        flightDetails.add(flightDetail1);*/

        for (FlightDetails flightDetail : flightDetails)
        {
            int depHour = Integer.valueOf(flightDetail.getDepTime().substring(0, 2));
            int depMin = Integer.valueOf(flightDetail.getDepTime().substring(2));

            int arrHour = Integer.valueOf(flightDetail.getArrTime().substring(0, 2));
            int arrMin = Integer.valueOf(flightDetail.getArrTime().substring(2));

            final Task st0 = new Task("On Time", date(day, (month-1), year, depHour,depMin), 
                    date(day, (month-1), year, arrHour,arrMin));
            t.addSubtask(st0);
        }
        s1.add(t);

        }

        model.add(s1);
        return model;
    }

    private static Date date(final int date, final int month, final int year, final int hourOfDay, final int minute) {

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month, date, hourOfDay, minute);
        final Date result = calendar.getTime();
        return result;

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final GanttDemo23 demo = new GanttDemo23("Gantt Chart Demo 23");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: This is the Gantt Chart]

This is the message I am getting. I want to display the subtask details instead.

[image: dialog image]

Comment: What's wrong with the message displayed? As readers can't access your database, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that includes suitable hard-codes dataset values..

Comment: The sample data has been displayed as blocked comments. This data shows the flight details. Each SubTask bar shows a different flight. I would like to display these flight details, once I click on the subTask bars in Gantt Chart.

Comment: This complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15241250/230513) assembles all subtask data  for each task in a tooltip.