# Customized Label To JFreeChart

Tags: label, jfreechart

I'm creating a XYStepChart using JFreeChart and my dataset is as sent to me as (TimeStamp, X1, X2). I'm required to plot X1 for a given timestamp, however I would want to use the value of X2 as the label for the given point.

Can someone please guide me in achieving this? I tried the following:

```
XYItemLabelGenerator itemLabelGenerator = new StandardXYItemLabelGenerator();
plot.getRenderer().setBaseItemLabelGenerator(itemLabelGenerator);
plot.getRenderer().setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(0, true);
```

But this just shows the value of X1 as labels. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most cases, you can use the *ArgumentIndex* values recognized by the [`StandardXYItemLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardXYItemLabelGenerator.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3158958/230513). For finer control, you can override `generateLabel()` in a subclass.

Comment: Thanks @trashgod for the suggestion. I achieved my requirement by overriding generateLabel() method. It worked :)