# Jfreechart TimeSeriesChart Label on Last Item

Tags: java, label, jfreechart, series, timeserieschart

I need a label on each last Item of all Series in Jfreechart's TimeSeriesChart.

The data I used is generated from a Database, so there's a way to get each last position of a Series.

**Before:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYOMc.png]

**After:**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVpMM.png]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Is it a question? Please state clearly if you need help with anything (is your "After" example a present state, or a desired solution?).

Comment: Hi Elist, it's a question of course. The "after" example is my desired solution. The question is, how to get there. I only get labels for all items, but not for specific the last one's of each series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a custom `XYItemLabelGenerator`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14459322/230513). Return `null` for each item in the series except the last.