# Override XYSeries add method to add a third String argument in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Can anyone tell me how to override the `XYSeries.add()` method, to add a 3rd argument as a String, so that the String text then lies inside the plot area? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds more like you need to extend from `XYSeries` class adding a new method that takes a different number of arguments instead of overriding an existing one. In any case as is this question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: And you will almost certainly need to  subclass the renderer for your chart too so as to actually display the Strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*JFreeChart line chart with text at each point*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14458402/230513), which `extends AbstractXYDataset`. If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: thanks .I will try your comments,if there is any link i can start with please share me @dic and steve.that(link) is not am looking for trashgod,there is a problem with that code try placing `ds.add(23, 50, "this a very long string");`  in the dataset.the string is not included inside plot.

Comment: The example uses an `XYItemLabelGenerator` and a `StandardXYToolTipGenerator`.

Comment: yes,is there any approach to place string inside the plot with series collections for multiple series ? I am looking at ValueMarker but it allows only one axis value,what i can see is that we cant palce it at (x,y) coordinates.any help on that trashgod.

Comment: Your implementation of `AbstractXYDataset` will have to handle multiple series; the example illustrates a single series.

Comment: can that implementation keep text(3rd argument) inside the plot trashgod ?