# Show stock split in candle chart jfreechart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, candlestick-chart, jfreechart-fx

Currently I'm working on charts and want to achieve an output.
I wanted to achieve two things.

1. To display candle stick chart of stocks data. [done]
2. To display the stock split log above or below the candle. [pending]

I'm using JFreeChart SDK to build the charts.
I'm using OHLCDataItem[] to build data for daily high/low etc of stock. unfortunately jfreechart does not have any extension of OHLCDataItem to show additional information (logo + text metadata) on the candle.

Sample code:

```
TimeSeries timeSeriesDailyMovingAverage = new TimeSeries("day moving average");
List<OHLCDataItem> dataItems = new ArrayList<OHLCDataItem>(); //to collect High low close prices

OHLCDataItem item = new OHLCDataItem(date, open, high, low, adjClose, volume);//this code is in loop with do that more data can be added for each day
dataItems.add(item);

OHLCDataItem[] data = dataItems.toArray(new OHLCDataItem[dataItems.size()]);
OHLCDataset dataset = new DefaultOHLCDataset(symbol, data);

//now initializing the candleStickRanderer and setting its properties series strock + paint
CandlestickRenderer CandleStickRenderer = new CandlestickRenderer();

XYLineAndShapeRenderer LineRenderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false);
HighLowRenderer OHLCRenderer = new HighLowRenderer();
DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis();

NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis();
rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createStandardTickUnits());
    
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, domainAxis, rangeAxis, LineRenderer);//set other properties
JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(info, new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 15), plot, false);
ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
getContentPane().add(panel);

XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
xyplot.setRenderer(CandleStickRenderer);
```

This is some rough code which is working fine. I'm getting the desired out of Candle chart.
[current output of candle stick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAhdu.png)
But I cannot figure out how can I add text/logo on XYPlot based on dataset.

**What I want to achieve is that, add text/or shape containing text information at the bottom/top of a particular candle.
It would be a great help if someone can guide me how I can do it based on the dataset.**

The desired output is like this chart.
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXuAf.png)

Or
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mt6B.png)

Comment: Maybe an `XYItemLabelGenerator`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20XYItemLabelGenerator)?

Comment: Also consider an annotation such as`XYTextAnnotation`.

Comment: Could this be what you are after? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14459322/7458162