# Dynamic tool tip generator - Jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am generating a dynamic chart (XYLineChart) using jFreeChart and I have a field which is not included in the dataset. The field is generated dynamically. I want to include that in my tooltip. Is there any possibility I can do it ?

Here is the flow of the program:

Create Chart using an empty dataset.

Set chartPanel. (I guess here is the place where we define the TooltipGenerator).

Receive dynamic data from socket.

Add data to the dataset. ( Here is the only place where I have the data which I need to have in my tooltip text).

Refresh Chart.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to care about data added dynamically to the dataset. Tooltips are created on the fly using the data from the dataset. The individual `XYToolTipGenerator` just needs to be assigned to the renderer instance.

As an example, start with the [`TimeSeriesChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1-source.html) class from `JFreeChart`, and add an individual `XYToolTipGenerator` as shown below.

```
XYItemRenderer r = plot.getRenderer();
…    
// define your own tooltip generator   
StandardXYToolTipGenerator tooltipGenerator = new StandardXYToolTipGenerator()
{
    @Override
    public String generateToolTip(XYDataset dataset, int series, int item)
    {
        return "Series " + series + " Item: " + item + " Value: "
            + dataset.getXValue(series, item) + ";"
            + dataset.getYValue(series, item);
    }
};
// and assign it to the renderer
r.setBaseToolTipGenerator(tooltipGenerator);
```

Comment: Also consider leveraging the `MessageFormat` values shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3158958/230513).

Comment: @trashgod : That's the problem I am facing. The name to be displayed is not included anywhere in the dataset. In the example you suggested, the company names are included in the legend. I do not have such a design in my project.

Comment: @Uli: I am sorry, but that approach would not work. I want to pass a specific data to the tooltip (if that's possible).

Comment: @AshwinVenkataraman: I've proposed an alternative [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31306690/230513) to complement Uli's suggestion.

Comment: the link is broken :(

Comment: Link is fixed now :-)

Answer (score 1):

> The name to be displayed is not included anywhere in the dataset.

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14459322/230513) for a custom `XYItemLabelGenerator`, you can extend a suitable dataset, e.g. `AbstractXYDataset`, to include the required information and access it from your implementation of `XYToolTipGenerator`.