# Jfreechart tooltip not working for timeseries

Tags: jfreechart

I'm trying to add a tooltip for the live (serial) data using a timeseries plot. However, the tooltip doesn't show up, so I'm not sure what is the problem and how I could fix it? Please suggest a way to solve this issue.

Comment: That's a different question. Look for `NumberAxis::setNumberFormatOverride` and see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Enable tooltips in your chosen `ChartFactory`. [`TimeSeriesChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.java), included in the distribution, is a complete example. From the [source](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/ad2112371b403721f922c2b34938d61653c16f0a/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.java#L78),

```
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
        "Legal & General Unit Trust Prices",  // title
        "Date",             // x-axis label
        "Price Per Unit",   // y-axis label
        dataset
    );
```

note that [`ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart()`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/a362a41d4d944f6be5d3ec2f93c32bc975e10c0b/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.java#L1920) enables tooltips by by [default](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/a362a41d4d944f6be5d3ec2f93c32bc975e10c0b/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.java#L1959).

If needed, create a custom `XYToolTipGenerator`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31279389/230513).