# XYdataset Jfreechart label plots with a third value

Tags: java, jfreechart, label

I am making a graph that shows me average according to a time. I have built an XYdataset (TimeSeries) where x-axis is time and y-axis is average.  I get the average from  this query:

```
select hour, avg(localizations) as avg, count(distinct tag) as cnt from hourly_tag_summaries where hour >= ? and tag in ("+ids+") group by hour;
```

This is how I created my dataset:

```
TimeSeries beacons_local = new TimeSeries("beacons-localizations");
String sql= "select hour, avg(localizations) as avg, count(distinct tag) as 
cnt from hourly_tag_summaries where hour >= ? and tag in ("+ids+") group by 
hour;";

    ResultSet rs1 = my_db.selectQuery(sql, Main.NOW - Main.DAYS);


    while (rs1.next()) {
        int avg = rs1.getInt("avg");
        long hour = rs1.getLong("hour");
        int cnt= rs1.getInt("cnt");
        beacons_local.add(new Millisecond(new Date(hour)),avg);

    }
```

I want to keep the cnt variable so when I mouse-over on the graph I can see the count for each plot. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each [`TimeSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html) in your [`TimeSeriesCollection`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeriesCollection.html), maintain a `List<Integer>` of counts. Reference the relevant count in your custom [`XYToolTipGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/XYToolTipGenerator.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14459322/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31287707/230513). The exact formulation depends on your use case; [`XYZDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYZDataset.html), and the corresponding [`XYZToolTipGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/XYToolTipGenerator.html), are examples that may serve as a guide.